# Reference for dayPeriod in Intl.DateTimeFormat

Tags: javascript, internationalization, datetime-format

What is `dayPeriod` in JavaScript `Intl.DateTimeFormat`, and what values can in take in the en-US locale? Also, does it have broad support in recent browsers?

I can't seem to find any reference.

Comment: Read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat#parameters

Comment: @RandyCasburn thx, but that doesn't seem to tell the different values dayPeriod can take. Only the formatting options.

Comment: Those are the values. What are you looking for?

Comment: Here: https://tc39.es/ecma402/#table-datetimeformat-components

Comment: For example: morning, noon, afternoon, etc. I wish I could tell you :-) Just like the possible values for weekday are Monday, Tuesday, etc.

Comment: I've given you both general and specific references. I recommend you study what it can do a bit, write some code and see what it does.

Answer (score 1):

The only reference I could find was this [Unicode Common Locale Data Repository (CLDR) table](https://unicode-org.github.io/cldr-staging/charts/37/supplemental/day_periods.html), and the associated [downloads page](http://cldr.unicode.org/index/downloads). I am not sure how browsers implement it.

Fun fact, the number of day periods varies across locales. English has 4 (morning, afternoon, evening, night), while for example German has 6.

An excerpt from the xml file:

```
<dayPeriodRules locales="root">
    <dayPeriodRule type="am" from="00:00" before="12:00"/>  <!-- AM -->
    <dayPeriodRule type="pm" from="12:00" before="24:00"/>  <!-- PM -->
</dayPeriodRules>
<dayPeriodRules locales="en">
    <dayPeriodRule type="midnight" at="00:00"/> <!-- midnight -->
    <dayPeriodRule type="noon" at="12:00"/> <!-- noon -->
    <dayPeriodRule type="morning1" from="06:00" before="12:00"/>    <!-- morning -->
    <dayPeriodRule type="afternoon1" from="12:00" before="18:00"/>  <!-- afternoon -->
    <dayPeriodRule type="evening1" from="18:00" before="21:00"/>    <!-- evening -->
    <dayPeriodRule type="night1" from="21:00" before="06:00"/>  <!-- night -->
</dayPeriodRules>
```